# Website Duplicate content detected with google webmaster

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter, url, web, seo

We have a website that is based on codeigniter with a wordpress blog in a sub directory. /blog.

Through using google webmaster tools and search results - we are seeing duplicate content mainly for our home page with the following shown after the domain name.

So for example a search on google for site:domainname.com on google shows:

```
domainname.com/?author=1
domainname.com/?author=2
domainname.com/?cat=1
domainname.com/?cat=3
domainname.com/?cat=4
/?feed=rss2&tag=drinking-establishments
/?feed=rss2&tag=fun
/?feed=rss2&tag=introduction
```

These appear to be generated all from the generated from the wordpress blog and we are not sure how to fix?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `robots.txt` file to tell Google what they should (and shouldn't) be looking for on your site.

A `robots.txt` file should live here: `example.com/robots.txt`

An example robots.txt as taken from the WordPress Codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Search_Engine_Optimization_for_WordPress

```
Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml

# Google Image
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow:
Allow: /*

# Google AdSense
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow:

# digg mirror
User-agent: duggmirror
Disallow: /

# global
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-content/plugins/
Disallow: /wp-content/cache/
Disallow: /wp-content/themes/
Disallow: /trackback/
Disallow: /feed/
Disallow: /comments/
Disallow: /category/*/*
Disallow: */trackback/
Disallow: */feed/
Disallow: */comments/
Disallow: /*?
Allow: /wp-content/uploads/
```

Background reading:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard